# 404 - Not Found Error RequestDispatcher jsp forward

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

I am trying to forward a Servlet to a JSP and I get this error when I click on the button that calls the doGet() that forwards into the JSP

> Type Status Report
>
> Message /servlet/crossfit/WOD
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

This is my Servlet code:

```
RequestDispatcher rd getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/app/crossfit/amrap.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
```

This is the mapping in my web.xml file

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>WOD</servlet-name>
    <description>Handle the workout generator and saver</description>
    <servlet-class>servlet.activity.crossfit.WOD</servlet-class>
</servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WOD</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/activity/crossfit/WOD</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

> <servlet-mapping>
>         <servlet-name>AmrapServlet</servlet-name>
>         <url-pattern>/app/crossfit/amrap.jsp</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>


> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>AmrapServlet</servlet-name>
>     <jsp-file>/app/crossfit/amrap.jsp</jsp-file> </servlet>
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwKIc.png)

Comment: The problem is not with the redirect to the jsp, but to find the servlet in the path. You should have a servlet mapping for your WOD servlet either in your web.xml or in the servlet itself (if you are using annotations). You don't need any servlet mapping for the jsp.

Comment: I already mapped the Servlet, I edited the question.

Comment: In the request the path activity is missing. Requested path is `/servlet/crossfit/WOD` and in your web.xml you have `/servlet/activity/crossfit/WOD`

Comment: So, where should I modify the request path?

Comment: You haven't included that part of the code, but you are describing a button click so I would assume that is where you have the request path as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!

Comment: Glad it worked. As it solved your problem I consolidated the comments into an answer. It would great if you could mark it as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the request the path `activity` is missing. Requested path is `/servlet/crossfit/WOD` and in your web.xml you have `/servlet/activity/crossfit/WOD`

Adjust in the code where you have the button your request path from `/servlet/crossfit/WOD` to `/servlet/activity/crossfit/WOD`